# How to check if an item belongs to a hasMany association before updating in CakePHP 3.2

Tags: sql, validation, cakephp, associations, has-many

**What I am trying to do:**

I have Estimates and Estimates have items "EstimateItems". When updating a Estimate the EstimateItems changed should update. (using patchEntity)

This is working with my current code, my only problem is that other users can edit the Estimate Items of other users when changing the primary key of a EstimateItem in the edit form, because when patching the existing EstimateItems CakePHP only looks at the primary key of the EstimateItem and doesn't take the association in consideration. Also it's still possible to edit the estimate_id of a EstimateItem while $protected estimate_id is set to false.

So what I need is CakePHP to validate that this EstimateItem belongs to the current association before updating or while trying to update.

I hope some one can tell me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing.

> **Current Query**

```
UPDATE 
  estimate_items 
SET 
  data = 'Test Query 1', 
  amount = 123456789, 
  tax_id = 3 
WHERE 
  id = 3
```

> **Expected Query**

```
UPDATE 
  estimate_items 
SET 
  data = 'Test Query 1', 
  amount = 123456789, 
  tax_id = 3 
WHERE 
  id = 3 AND estimate_id = 1
```

**Current code:**

> **Estimates -> Edit.ctp**

```
<?php $this->Form->templates($formTemplates['default']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->create($estimate, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Offerte') ?></legend>

        <?= $this->Form->input('reference', ['label' => __('#Referentie'), 'autocomplete' => 'off']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('client_id',
            [
                'type' => 'select',
                'empty' => true,
                'label' => __('Klant'),
                'options' => $clients
            ]
        )
        ?>

        <?php

        foreach($estimate->estimate_items as $key => $item){
        ?>
        <div class="item">
            <legend>Item</legend>
            <?= $this->Form->hidden('estimate_items.'. $key .'.id') ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('estimate_items.'. $key .'.data', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => __('Beschrijving')]) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('estimate_items.'. $key .'.amount', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => __('Bedrag'), 'class' => 'input-date']) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('estimate_items.'. $key .'.tax_id',
                [
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'empty' => true,
                    'label' => __('Belasting type'),
                    'options' => $taxes
                ]
            )
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }

        ?>

        <legend>Informatie</legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('date', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => __('Offerte datum'), 'autocomplete' => 'off']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('expiration', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => __('Verloop datum'), 'autocomplete' => 'off']) ?>
   </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Save')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

> **Estimates Controller**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class EstimatesController extends AppController
{
public function edit($id){
        $associated = ['EstimateItems'];

        $estimate = $this->Estimates->get($id, ['contain' => $associated]);

        $this->log($estimate);
        if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

            $estimate = $this->Estimates->patchEntity($estimate, $this->request->data, [
                'associated' => $associated
            ]);

            $estimate->total = '0';
            $this->log($estimate);
            $this->log($this->request->data);

            if($this->Estimates->save($estimate, ['associated' => $associated])){
                $this->Flash->success(__('De offerte is bijgewerkt'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
        }

        $this->set('taxes', $this->Estimates->Taxes->find('list', [ 'keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'tax_name' ]));
        $this->set('clients', $this->Estimates->Clients->find('list', [ 'keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'companyname' ]));
        $this->set('estimate', $estimate);
    }
}
```

> **EstimatesTable**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;

class EstimatesTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'hasOne' => ['Taxes'],
            'belongsTo' => ['Companies', 'Clients'],
            'hasMany' => ['EstimateItems' => [
                'foreignKey' => 'estimate_id'
            ]]
        ]);

    }

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules){

        // A Node however should in addition also always reference a Site.
       $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['estimate_id'], 'EstimateItems'));

        return $rules;
    }

}
```

> **EstimateItem Entity**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class EstimateItem extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => false,
        'data' => true,
        'amount' => true,
        'tax_id' => true,
        'unit_id' => true
    ];
}
```

> **EstimateItemsTable**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
use Cake\ORM\Query;


class EstimateItemsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
      $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => ['Estimates' => ['foreignKey' => 'estimate_id']],
            'hasOne' => ['Taxes' => ['foreignKey' => 'tax_id']]
        ]);
    }
```

> **Estimate Entity**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Estimate extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => false,
        'id' => false,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Are you just assuming that this can happen, or have you actually tested it? Given your `$_accessible` configuration, neither `id` nor `estimate_id` should ever make it from the request data into the entities.

Comment: This is tested. I also did not expect the behaviour you mention that's why I will make a post tomorrow on the cake github and ask why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markstory Replied to me on github with a solution credits to him:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9527

**In Model/Table/EstimateItemsTable.php**

---

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
....
class EstimateItemsTable extends Table
{
....
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules){
        $rules->addUpdate(function($entity) {

          if (!$entity->dirty('estimate_id')) {
            return true;
          }
          return $entity->estimate_id == $entity->getOriginal('estimate_id');
        }, 'ownership', ['errorField' => 'estimate_id']);

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to implement the check via a beforeSave callback function if you don't trust that setting fields hidden / not editable is not enough.

In the callBack you can check if the relation was already there before before you overwrite them with a wrongly edited value.

Comment: So there is no build in solution for this by Cake? So you say I should do a query on each individual EstimateItem to check whether it's associated with the current Estimate or not? Is there no way to add a where clause in the update query?

Comment: I am not sure about CakePhp3 I have more experience with CaePhp2, but if you can solve the problem with a special query you are free to overwrite the normal saving behaviour.
However what I would do is: 
* make sure nobody messes with the inital data
* if that is not possible write a callback

Comment: I think I am going to make a post on their github if no one knows a built in solution for cake and ask one of the developers what the best solution is. But I will take your answers in consideration. I will probably use the beforeSave if there is no other solution.